# finding the voltage gain for an amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, gain

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMshUF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hello all
the circuit provided represents the small signal model of a MOSFET amplifier.
I am being asked to find Vo/Vsig which is the total voltage gain of this amplifier. My analysis is below:

\begin{equation}
v_{sig}\:=\:-i\left(\frac{1}{g_m}+R_D\backslash \backslash \left(R_1+R_2\right)\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_o\:=\:-i\left(R_D\backslash \backslash \left(R_1+R_2\right)\right)
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\frac{v_o}{v_{sig}}=\:\frac{R_D\backslash \backslash \left(R_1+R_2\right)}{R_D\backslash \:\backslash \:\left(R_1+R_2\right)+\frac{1}{g_m}}
\end{equation}
but the problem is that the book answer is this:
\begin{equation}
\frac{v_o}{v_{sig}}=\:\frac{1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}}{1+\frac{\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}{g_m\left(R_D\backslash \backslash \left(R_1+R_2\right)\right)}}
\end{equation}
The problem seems simple, but I don't know what am doing wrong. Any help please?

Comment: Your equation for Vsig is not true.  Notice that \$V_G = Vin + V_{GS} \$

Comment: But isn't Vgs = Vsig??

Comment: No, in this case. Vgs is a voltage drop across 1/gm, \$Vgs = Vo*\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - V_{sig} \$

Comment: Sorry but am confused now, but VG = Vo * (R1/(R1+R2)) how could VGS be the same as VG??

Comment: Vgs is 
(Vg - Vsig)

Comment: But your definition of Vgs makes Vsig zero

Comment: What? How is so?